# Nautilus isn't minimizing but opening a new session every time the icon is clicked

Tags: nautilus, icons, plank

To clarify, when I click an icon in [plank](https://launchpad.net/plank) it opens a window of the respective app. If I click that icon again it gets minimized like it should. But when I do the same with Nautilus it opens up a new window with new session of the application. I don't want that to happen and I remember that it wasn't always like this.

When I open it through Gnome dash (on the right) it doesn't show this behavior. The problem is only in Plank.

Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons in the Dash and in the Launcher uses different `.desktop`-files. The icon in the launcher uses `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`, the icon in the Dash uses `nautilus.desktop`. Starting Nautilus from the different location will add different icons (with the same look) to the `plank`-dock.

I added both icons to the dock to get some meaningful output and they have different behavior. The `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`icon will behave as you want, it will minimize all open Nautilus-windows and rise all off them clicking the icon again. The `nautilus.desktop`-icon behaves as you describe, it will always open a new Nautilus-window.

You will find the launcher-entries for the `plank`-dock in

```
~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers
```

Here some output from my configuration:

```
$ ls -l '/home/mook/.config/plank/dock1/launchers' 
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mook mook 83 พ.ค.  15 19:46 firefox.dockitem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mook mook 84 พ.ค.  15 20:12 nautilus.dockitem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mook mook 91 พ.ค.  15 19:50 org.gnome.gedit.dockitem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mook mook 94 พ.ค.  15 19:47 org.gnome.Nautilus.dockitem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mook mook 94 พ.ค.  15 19:47 org.gnome.Terminal.dockitem</pre>
```

Content of `org.gnome.Nautilus.dockitem`:

```
[PlankDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

Content of `nautilus.dockitem`:
nautilus.dockitem

```
[PlankDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

When you check the files in `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers`, I am sure you will find `nautilus.dockitem` as this is the one which behave as you described. To remove the icon from the dock, close all Nautilus-windows, right-click the icon in the `plank`-dock and un-check `Keep in Dock`. Then start Nautilus from the Launcher (you will probably have to add Nautilus to favorites before) and lock the new Nautilus-icon in the `plank`-dock with right-click and checking `Keep in dock`.

Confusing, isn't it?

A funny thing is that I can't find the files `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` and `nautilus.desktop` with Nautilus, but they are listed when I use`ls -a /usr/share/applications` in the terminal...

**Tested in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04**

Comment: It really did the job

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Great, was not easy to find out, still had Ubuntu Gnome installed from our last meeting, so I installed `plank` (amazing app) to test it out, was a good fun!

Comment: it's seriously amazing, right? (rhetorical)

Comment: Yes, it looks like Nautilus is started via dbus, that make things very different from earlier set-ups.